# Is there a way to return IActionResult type without being an async function

Tags: c#, async-await

```
public Task<IActionResult> sample() 
{
do stuff NOT await
return Ok();
}
```

I know this will work if do stuff has an await function call somewhere, but I want to use the IActionResult return for non-Async functions.
Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `public IActionResult sample() {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1#iactionresult-type) outline a synchronous example that returns `IActionResult`.

It is simply defined as a method that returns `IActionResult` (without being wrapped in a `Task`):

```
public IActionResult GetById(int id)
```

The method then returns one out of a couple of very descriptively named implementations of `IActionResult`, in this case `NotFound` or `Ok`, in order to indicate different outcomes of the operation.